# nvarchar column size impact on performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, nvarchar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [overstating field size in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025996/overstating-field-size-in-database-design)

I have a "description" column in one of my tables which as of now I dont know the maximum size of. But I am assuming it should not be greater than 1000 characters.

Question: If I make it nvarchar(4000) [just to be safe] will it have any adverse impact on performance ?

Thanks.

Comment: This was JUST asked a couple of days back.  See the linked question.

Comment: no problem, happy to minimize the noise :)

Answer (score 3):

No. `NVARCHAR(1000)` has all the exact characteristics as `NVARCHAR(4000)`. As a variable length column it takes only the space it needs, it can be pushed out-of-row if it does not fit in page and so on and so forth.

On a related note, if you'd use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` then you could experience some degradation, usually not noticeable though, see [Performance comparison of varchar(max) vs. varchar(N)](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/). Also a MAX type would prevent online rebuild and index operations.

Comment: Can you repost this on the linked question?  I think it would be great to have  this info there